# Is there a difference between set in a batch file and cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In my certain circumstance an executable I run with

```
set VAR1=SOMEVAR && process.exe
```

Does not work.
However, a batch file with

```
set VAR1=SOMEVAR
```

works by running it like:

```
setvar.bat && process.exe
```

It has been verified process.exe does run in both cases.

The exe I'm using is bacwi.exe and the sourceforge page mentions

"bvlc.bat batch file configures environment variables to use BACnet/IP port 47809 for any *subsequent* BACnet tools run from that command prompt window, and enables the BBMD Foreign Device Registration."

Comment: Are you aware that the first example would include the space between `R` and `&&` in the value assigned, but the second would not? Given the generality of your question, and your explicit problem description `does not work`, you're crossong into crystal-ball territory.

Comment: No I am not aware of that !! That may be the issue. I will return with the results.

Comment: @Magoo you were correct! Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you aware that the first example would include the space between R and && in the value assigned, but the second would not? Given the generality of your question, and your explicit problem description does not work, you're crossing into crystal-ball territory